# Method called without passing parameters

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in C#. I encountered below code snippet in my project. I do not understand how `ViewHelper.IsInView` has been called without passing any parameters. Could anyone explain me this. Thanks in advance.

```
public static class ViewHelper
{
  public static bool IsInView(IFrameworkElement element)
  {
  ----------
  }
}

var Result = Views.Any(ViewHelper.IsInView);
```

Comment: is there any other overload of IsInView in ViewHelper?

Comment: No, there is no any overload of IsInView

Comment: It is using the current view (which contains left, top, width, height) and passing the element (which also has the left, top, width, height).  Framework has the capability of getting property values by the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Any` method accepts a delegate - a pointer to a function - of the form `Func<T, bool>`. Meaning it expects a method that accepts an element of the type of the collection (I'm guessing `IFrameworkElement` in your case) and returns a `bool` - which is exactly the signature of the `IsInView` method.

The `Any` method then executes this delegate on elements in the `Views` collection until it encounters one that returns `true`.

In C#, there is an implicit conversion from a "method group" to a delegate type. Essentially, when you write

```
Views.Any(ViewHelper.IsInView)
```

It translates into

```
Views.Any(new Func<IFrameworkElement, bool>(ViewHelper.IsInView))
```

Answer (score 3):

What is being passed to [`Enumerable.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) is a *delegate*, the method is not being called at this point.  If there are any views then `Any` will call that delegate with one or more of the views as the argument.

The delegate you're passing to `Any` has been created through something known as *implicit method group conversion*.

`Views.Any` is expecting a delegate of the type `Func<IFrameworkElement, bool>`, meaning it takes a single parameter of type `IFrameworkElement` and returns `bool`. You can create such a delegate from your method, as the signatures are compatible.  This is how you would *explicitly* do this:

```
Func<IFrameworkElement, bool> predicate = 
    new Func<IFrameworkElement, bool>(ViewHelper.IsInView);
```

However, from C# 2.0 such a conversion can be done *implicitly*, meaning this code is exactly the same:

```
Func<IFrameworkElement, bool> predicate = ViewHelper.IsInView;
```